# tkinter, metodo .get no retorna nada

Tags: python, tkinter, método

El problema es que a pesar de que escribo algo en los campos Entry, y los enlazo correctamente a una variable, al momento de evaluarlos con el .get y ver lo que obtuvieron, me devuelve nulo.

```
   ventana_añadir = Tk()
    ventana_añadir.title("Añadir un Usuario")
    ventana_añadir.geometry("550x200+600+250")
    ventana_añadir.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    nombre = StringVar()
    apellido = StringVar()
    id = StringVar()
    edad = StringVar()
    salario = StringVar()
    seleccion = Label(ventana_añadir, text = "Añadir Nueva Entrada", font = ("Times", 25)).place(x = 100, y = 10)
    Nombre_Label = Label(ventana_añadir, text = "Nombre ").place(x= 39, y = 70)
    Apellido_Label = Label(ventana_añadir, text = "Apellidos ").place(x = 239, y = 70)
    Edad_Label= Label(ventana_añadir, text = "Edad").place(x = 37, y = 110)
    Salario_Label = Label(ventana_añadir, text = "Salario").place(x = 100, y = 110)
    Nombre_Entry = Entry(ventana_añadir, textvariable = nombre, width = 30).place(x = 40, y = 90)
    Apellido_Entry = Entry(ventana_añadir, textvariable = apellido, width = 45).place(x = 240, y = 90)
    Edad_Spinbox = Spinbox(ventana_añadir, textvariable = edad, from_ = 10 , to = 99, state = "readonly", width = 5).place(x = 40, y = 130)
    Salario_Entry = Entry(ventana_añadir, textvariable = salario, width = 15).place(x = 100, y = 130)
    Añadir_Button = Button(ventana_añadir, text = "Añadir", font = ("Helvetica", 18),command = lambda: verificar_datos(str(nombre.get()), str(apellido.get()), str(edad.get()), str(salario.get()))).place(x = 240 , y = 120)
    ID_Label = Label(ventana_añadir, text = "ID").place(x = 39, y = 150 )
    ID_Entry = Entry(ventana_añadir, textvariable = id, state = "readonly").place(x = 40, y = 170)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ya lo resolví, si alguien tiene el mismo problema, lo que se debe hacer es especificar dentro de StringVar() la ventana sobre la cual se estarán creando las variables.

ejemplo

ventana = Tk()
var = StringVar(ventana)

Answer (score 0):

He probado tu código, como no se que hace la función de `verificar_datos`, he hecho que imprima los datos:

from tkinter import *

```
def verificar_datos(nom, apell, ed, sal):
    print(nom)
    print(apell)
    print(ed)
    print(sal)

ventana_añadir = Tk()
ventana_añadir.title("Añadir un Usuario")
ventana_añadir.geometry("550x200+600+250")
ventana_añadir.resizable(width=False, height=False)
nombre = StringVar()
apellido = StringVar()
id = StringVar()
edad = StringVar()
salario = StringVar()
seleccion = Label(ventana_añadir, text="Añadir Nueva Entrada", font=("Times", 25)).place(x=100, y=10)
Nombre_Label = Label(ventana_añadir, text="Nombre ").place(x=39, y=70)
Apellido_Label = Label(ventana_añadir, text="Apellidos ").place(x=239, y=70)
Edad_Label = Label(ventana_añadir, text="Edad").place(x=37, y=110)
Salario_Label = Label(ventana_añadir, text="Salario").place(x=100, y=110)
Nombre_Entry = Entry(ventana_añadir, textvariable=nombre, width=30).place(x=40, y=90)
Apellido_Entry = Entry(ventana_añadir, textvariable=apellido, width=45).place(x=240, y=90)
Edad_Spinbox = Spinbox(ventana_añadir, textvariable=edad, from_=10, to=99, state="readonly", width=5).place(x=40, y=130)
Salario_Entry = Entry(ventana_añadir, textvariable=salario, width=15).place(x=100, y=130)
Añadir_Button = Button(ventana_añadir, text="Añadir", font=("Helvetica", 18),
                       command=lambda: verificar_datos(nombre.get(), apellido.get(), str(edad.get()),
                                                       str(salario.get()))).place(x=240, y=120)
ID_Label = Label(ventana_añadir, text="ID").place(x=39, y=150)
ID_Entry = Entry(ventana_añadir, textvariable=id, state="readonly").place(x=40, y=170)
ventana_añadir.mainloop()
```

Y me funciona:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Salida:

```
nombre
Apellidos
14
1000.0
```

Además no es necesario pasarles los valores de las variables a la función ya que los `StringVar` son variables globales.

```
from tkinter import *


def verificar_datos():
    print(nombre.get())
    print(apellido.get())
    print(edad.get())
    print(salario.get())

ventana_añadir = Tk()
ventana_añadir.title("Añadir un Usuario")
ventana_añadir.geometry("550x200+600+250")
ventana_añadir.resizable(width=False, height=False)
nombre = StringVar()
apellido = StringVar()
id = StringVar()
edad = StringVar()
salario = StringVar()
seleccion = Label(ventana_añadir, text="Añadir Nueva Entrada", font=("Times", 25)).place(x=100, y=10)
Nombre_Label = Label(ventana_añadir, text="Nombre ").place(x=39, y=70)
Apellido_Label = Label(ventana_añadir, text="Apellidos ").place(x=239, y=70)
Edad_Label = Label(ventana_añadir, text="Edad").place(x=37, y=110)
Salario_Label = Label(ventana_añadir, text="Salario").place(x=100, y=110)
Nombre_Entry = Entry(ventana_añadir, textvariable=nombre, width=30).place(x=40, y=90)
Apellido_Entry = Entry(ventana_añadir, textvariable=apellido, width=45).place(x=240, y=90)
Edad_Spinbox = Spinbox(ventana_añadir, textvariable=edad, from_=10, to=99, state="readonly", width=5).place(x=40, y=130)
Salario_Entry = Entry(ventana_añadir, textvariable=salario, width=15).place(x=100, y=130)
Añadir_Button = Button(ventana_añadir, text="Añadir", font=("Helvetica", 18),
                       command=verificar_datos).place(x=240, y=120)
ID_Label = Label(ventana_añadir, text="ID").place(x=39, y=150)
ID_Entry = Entry(ventana_añadir, textvariable=id, state="readonly").place(x=40, y=170)
ventana_añadir.mainloop()
```

Comment: Mmmmm, que raro, hice lo mismo que tu de imprimirlos, sin embargo no me mostraba nada, supongo que es un error del IDE. (Estoy usando Pycharm).

Comment: @CesarCuevas Yo tambien he usado Pycharm

Comment: Lo volví a probar y sigue retornando nulo :(

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu tiempo, ya pude solucionarlo, las StringVars se estaban creado con contextos de otra ventana, lo único que hice fue 

nombre = StringVar(ventana_añadir)

y asi con las otras variables, por eso a ti te funcionaba, porque solo tenias una ventana abierta. De todas formas te agradezco mucho.

Comment: @CesarCuevas coloca tu observación en tu pregunta para que otros puedan solucionar un problema similar :D